# DownThemAll - Wait page until finish loading then download

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using [DownThemAll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DownThemAll!) with Firefox. I've several links like this:

```
site1.com/1.html
site1.com/2.html
site1.com/3.html
etc....
```

I want to download these HTML pages with DownThemAll.
The problem is: These HTML pages have ressources, so they have to be fully loaded to be downloaded (I've to wait until the page is loaded to download it).

So DownThemAll isn't downloading me the full page loaded. DownThemAll Enter to the pages then downloading them EMPTY...

So is there any option in DownThemAll or a similar software (like DownThemAll) ...that do this JOB?!

Comment: Could you actually name a site? DownThemAll just requests the page and doesn't do any processing of script etc. and even other crawlers (from what I know) rarely try to do that.

Comment: What you think of wget -w TIME ? , is -w TIME to load the page then download it ? . i'll test With : wget .

Comment: Site Grabbers (DTA! isn’t one) don’t “load” pages. They don’t have to, because they can parse HTML. Site Grabbers usually cannot deal with client-side interactivity.